# How to sum amount per date?

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with two columns: A is a date and B is the amount.
I want to calculate how much did i make per day.

I have tried different codes i found online but they didn't work,

Such as:

My Data ex:

```
1/12/2015 
1/12/2015 
1/12/2015 -45.28
1/12/2015 
1/12/2015 146.23
1/12/2015 -95.03
1/12/2015 
1/12/2015 
1/12/2015 76.91
1/12/2015 
1/12/2015 
1/12/2015 
2/12/2015 
2/12/2015 155.42
2/12/2015 102.18
```

My Funcation:

```
=IF(ROUND((CELL("row",A4)/4),0)=(CELL("row",A4)/4),SUM(A1:OFFSET(A4,0,0)),"")
```

Can you please help me with finding the code i need?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) function?

Comment: yes but im not sure how to use it correct for my problem

Comment: A pivot table would do this easily.

Comment: im new with this think you can explain to me how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the techniques in [this](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/ to first create a unique list) page to create a unique list of dates. Use the [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) Function to find the sum matching each unique date.

> You can also use cell references that define the date range criteria.
>   For example, if you enter the date 1/31/2013 in cell D1, all cells
>   between B2 and B32 are summed:
>
> =SUMIF(A2:A32,"="&D1,B2:B32)

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use a pivot table.  Drag dates to the Rows area, and Amounts to the Values area.  Set the Value field settings to `Sum`, and format to taste:

[image]